# Updating a nested map within a vector within a map

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a map within a vector within a map.

```
{ :label "Apparel & Accessories", 
  :img_class "itm_3", 
  :children [
             {:id "sub1", 
              :label "Clothing", 
              :markup [:div] 
             } 
             {:id "sub2", 
              :label "Shoes & Footwear", 
              :markup [:div] 
             } 
   ] 
}  `
```

What I want to do is dissoc the key :markup from all entries. I've been struggling with this for 2 hours. Only far I got is dissoc the key :children. 
But the requirement is to remove :markup key only.

So final output should be

```
{ :label "Apparel & Accessories", 
  :img_class "itm_3", 
  :children [
             {:id "sub1", 
              :label "Clothing", 
             } 
             {:id "sub2", 
              :label "Shoes & Footwear", 
             } 
   ]
}   `
```

Any contribution is highly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to consider Specter, which does what you want in one line of code: https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter#specter-

Answer (score 2):

It is a good habit to make the alteration 'all in one go':

```
(update m :children (fn [v] (assert (vector? v)) (mapv #(dissoc % :markup) v)))
```

Here `m` is only being referred to once. It would matter for instance if you were doing a `swap!`.

If you don't have a vector, yet want to create one on the fly then this will work:

```
(update m :children (fn [xs]
                      (->> xs
                           vec
                           (mapv #(dissoc % :markup)))))
```

But on the other hand there is no real need to be using vectors. The original solution without the `assert` works fine when `:children` is set to:

```
'({:id    "sub1",
  :label  "Clothing",
  :markup [:div]}
 {:id     "sub2",
  :label  "Shoes & Footwear",
  :markup [:div]})
```

Comment: I think my map is Lazy. With your solution I get an error "ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative"

Comment: AssertionError Assert failed: (vector? v)

Comment: So your data is different to that in your question. You can use `into []` to change your data. But I'll take out the assert and make it work locally...

Comment: Data not much different but bigger. Some has many data within :children some has nil.

Comment: Again error IllegalArgumentException Key must be integer

Comment: You might like to take some time and isolate exactly what causes the problem, and ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Really appreciate it.

Comment: By the way a `map` can't be lazy. I think the problem is that where you think there are maps there are really seqs.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in two steps, not one unfortunately.

```
(def m { :label "Apparel & Accessories", :img_class "itm_3", :children [ {:id "sub1", :label "Clothing", :markup [:div] } {:id "sub2", :label "Shoes & Footwear", :markup [:div] } ] })

(defn dissoc-markup [child]
  (dissoc child :markup))

(update m :children #(mapv dissoc-markup %))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you want to remove :markup whenever you see it, here is a simple way to do it:

```
(def your-data {:your-data "...."})
(clojure.walk/postwalk (fn [m] 
                         (if (map? m) 
                           (dissoc m :markup) 
                           m))
                       your-data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your initial map is `m`, a possible solution is this

```
(assoc m :children (mapv #(dissoc % :markup) (m :children)))
```

It takes the value of `:children`, removes the `:markup` keys and replaces the result to the initial map.

Comment: I get an error "ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn"